# Hadoop install on computer or virtual machine?

Tags: macos, hadoop, virtual-machine, apple-m1, parallels

I have a school project that requires Hadoop installation (It is basically so we get familiar with it. I don't see it needing further applications). Would you recommend installing it on my computer (I have a mac with M1) or using parallels and installing it in a windows VM?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely not recommend a Windows environment for Hadoop, virtual or not.

If it's a throw away environment, a VM (or Docker setup) would be preferred. However, it's easiest installed directly on the host (`brew install hadoop`), and will therefore have full access to your machine for multi threading.

Alternatively, cloud providers offer schools deep discounts, and a cluster of several machines  is a few clicks away rather than needing to tune everything just for your one machine.